Calling an asynchronous method causes a debug
I ran into a problem while developing a program on UWP. I need to open a dialog box for the user to select a save folder. When calling the method StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); the program calls the debugger.
The complete method:
private async void OpenFolderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
        filePath.Text = file.Path;
}

I tried to look at the code examples on the Microsoft website.

"the program calls the debugger" - what exactly does that mean? Does it show an exception that's being thrown? If so, share it inculding stacktrace and full message (as text, not image).

Do a cross check that you have not already mark the line for stack tracing, normally a red circle will show up next to the line number on left side of code + you should use run button instead of debug

^^ those "red dot" are called "breakpoints". Maybe invoke a menu item that says "Remove (or delete, something of that notion) all breakpoints".

Are you sure it's a UWP app and not a WinUI 3 app?

Use try catch, debugger and log when the code enters the if statement to trace the cause of issue the more info you provide the bigger chance someone will help you solve this issue, also use watch to see what is inside of the variables you are using. you can also step into the PickSingleFileAsync() itself

You should add FileTypeFilter to specify file types.
       FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
       openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
       openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
       // set file type to show
       openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
       StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

For more details you could refer to the Doc:Pick a single file: step-by-step
